# Odoo security, prevent a logged user from accessing unprotected tables with jsonrpc?

Tags: security, odoo, odoo-9

Whatever is done on an XML view and if no access control/record rules is defined, any use could get any information on Odoo with a simple JS snippet:

```
(new window.openerp.web.Model('my.model')).query().all().then(f=>console.log(f))
```

- What could be done to prevent that?
- Is defining access control and record rules the only way?
- Is there any mechanism that would prevent the user from accessing anything that is not accessible to him through the current action/view?

Comment: Odoo uses access control and record rules for this kind of requirement? of curse you can use your own mechanism in the code. are you looking for an alternative did you have some problem with this mechanism? some performance issue for example

Comment: I am wondering if access control and record rules will not introduce unexpected issues back-end side. For instance, I want someone only to see invoices but not all account.move, I would add a rule to prevent all read on account.move. This would do what I need user-side but what if somewhere in the invoice save process the model account.move is actually used? With the new security rule something unexpected might happen back-end side..

Comment: Yes you mostly going to find this We call them Bugs. I think CZoellner covers all, to prevent this from happening use the sudo to bypass this restrictions when ever is needed, because this is a special cases for you in General odoo code was not designed to handle this rare situation. but everything can be fixed you need to test your code well and fix the issues that accures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually access control and record rules are the way to go. The whole security is about them. So if you don't have those rules for some technical or business models, while requiring them to not be seen by a logged-in user, then your own concept of those models is wrong or not well thought out.

And you also can define very strict rules while bypassing them with admin rights (sudo). That's usually needed in computed fields, which depend on data a "normal" user shouldn't see but is needed for the computation.